# How do I view my class model using xcode4 or another tool?

Tags: xcode4

Is there a way to view the entire class model for my project graphically? I have several classes and I'd like to see things like someClass 'is a' window and 'has a' frame. I know I could use something like OMNIGRAFFLE and make one myself but is there something built into xcode4 or some other tool that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Visual Paragdim UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) for that. It creates both code from UML and an UML graph from code.
Check out [this tutorial](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/276/277/7284_reverseengin.html) to see how.

Comment: The community edition (free) does NOT generate diagrams. In order to get that you have to purchase at least the standard edition.

Comment: That is true, I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Previous versions of Xcode had a class modeler but this was removed in Xcode 4. Presumably it wasn't a popular enough feature to make the cut into v4. No word on whether they plan to add it back into some future 4.x version.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this to help me analyse an existing project that I'll have to maintain and I found [Autograf](http://autograf.sourceforge.net/). Even though it seems not to be actively maintained it still works.